# After upgrading Java my tests in jruby are not working anymore, due to no finding Java anymore

Tags: java, ruby, intellij-idea, upgrade

I upgraded Java to version jre1.8.0_221. My JAVA_HOME is also changed to the correct new location, but intelliJ gives the message: "Cannot locate Java installation, specified by JAVA_HOME.

I've checked the project settings in IntelliJ: Project SDK is set correctly, Module is set correctly. Platform settings: SDK's are defined.

Comment: did you give the path of the `{path_to_java}/bin` in IntelliJ?

Comment: Yes, I gave the path in my WIndows settings

Comment: Tip: It's "Java" not "JAVA".